# In Python how do you pop the first n elements of a list and append these to a new list?

Tags: python

How do I pop the first n elements of a list and append these to a different list?

so, for example.

```
mylist = []
n = 3
mainlist = [5,4,3,2,1]
```

How would I make it so I have

```
mainlist = [2,1]

mylist = [5,4,3]
```

I've tried the following but it doesn't work as the placement of the elements are changing after each loop:

```
for i in list(range(n)):
    mylist.append(mainlist.pop(i))
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging whatsoever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just slice the list:

```
mainlist = [5,4,3,2,1]
n = 3
mainlist, mylist= a[:n], a[n:]
```

Keep in mind that for slicing, the first index is inclusive, while the second is exclusive, so mainlist wouldn't contain index 3 but mylist would.

Comment: Write a "hello world" program for me. I was able to write only hello using print("hello")

Comment: That's how you do it.

Comment: It was a sarcastic comment. I feel the question is such a trivial one that a comment on the official documentation of list slicing or pop command would have been great. The OP has simply pasted his requirements rather than researching well enough

Comment: Ah I thought you were the OP :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do slicing and `del`.

Slicing to obtain first `n` elements.
`del` to delete first `n` elements.

```
mainlist = [5,4,3,2,1]
lst = mainlist[:3]
del mainlist[:3]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code will append the first two elements from `list1` to the `list2`:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d']
list2 = []

for i in list1[:2]:
    list2.append(i)

print(list2)
```

Cheers!

Comment: This does not answer the part of the question of how to remove the elements from the first list

Answer (score 0):

None of the other answers change the list in place. 
It needs very little modification of the original code, just change the .pop(i) to .pop(0), because each time you remove the first element.

```
   for i in list(range(n)):
        mylist.append(mainlist.pop(0))
```